# State set in WillMount() not accessible in DidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, state

I have a component that requires an API get request to retrieve some information on `componentDidMount()`. That get request relies on information stored in state that I am setting through functions called, on `ComponentWillMount()`.

My `willMount()` runs, then I hit my `render()` method, but the state has not been set, and so then it hits `didMount()` but fails because the data is not in state yet. Where am I going wrong?

Edit: all functions are bound in the constructor (not shown)

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.enforceEmployeeAuth();
    this.loadEmployeeInfo();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchSurveyFields();
  }

  // Initial check to confirm if the user should be allowed to access any information.
  enforceEmployeeAuth() {
    // Get request to confirm that the current user is of type EMPLOYEE
    API.get("user/employee_auth", {}, (res) => {
      // Employee Auth: True if employee, else false
      this.setState({
        employee_auth: res.employee_auth,
      });
    });
  }

  // Load up relevant information for currentUser/employee
  loadEmployeeInfo() {
    API.get("client/currentEmployee", {}, function(res) {
      this.setState({
        employee              : res.employee,
        employee_company      : res.employee_company,
      })
    }.bind(this));
  }

  fetchSurveyFields() {
    debugger
    API.get('client/survey', {
      survey: this.state.employee_company.survey_name
    }, function(res) {
      debugger
    })
  }

  render() {

    debugger

    return (
      <h2 className="text-charcoal text-left">Employee Rubric</h2>
    )
  }
```

Comment: you're going to need to wait for the results of .get to come back before you can use the data

Comment: Did u check whether state has been properly set with data inside loadEmployeeInfo() method when called from componentWillMount() method

Comment: I checked the flow with debuggers. It is as follows:
`willMount()` --> runs functions....
`render()` --> no state update...
`didMount()` --> state isn't altered still and function will fail....
`render()` --> first state change is rendered....
`render()` --> second state change is rendered

Comment: @Cruiser I think you're right, but how do I prevent the rest of my stuff from running until I receive the results?

Comment: your `API.get` returns a promise which is not yet fulfilled when your `componentDidMount` runs - that's why your state has no data yet

Comment: @vin_Bin87 it looks like you're wanting to use the data from fetchSurveyResults in render(), so I would just move that function call to WillMount and wait for it to get the data with promises

Answer (score 2):

You should save the promises returned by both api calls. And then on resolution of those in componentDidMount, you should make api call for fetchSurveyFields. Like this

```
  componentWillMount() {
    this.promises = [];

    this.promises.push(this.enforceEmployeeAuth());
    this.promises.push(this.loadEmployeeInfo());
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Promise.all(this.promises)
      .then(([resp1, resp2]) => {
         //You can see here if you still wanna set state.
         this.fetchSurveyFields();
      });

  }

  // Initial check to confirm if the user should be allowed to access any information.
  enforceEmployeeAuth() {
    // Get request to confirm that the current user is of type EMPLOYEE
    API.get("user/employee_auth", {}, (res) => {
      // Employee Auth: True if employee, else false
      this.setState({
        employee_auth: res.employee_auth,
      });
    });
  }

  // Load up relevant information for currentUser/employee
  loadEmployeeInfo() {
    API.get("client/currentEmployee", {}, function(res) {
      this.setState({
        employee              : res.employee,
        employee_company      : res.employee_company,
      })
    }.bind(this));
  }

  fetchSurveyFields() {
    debugger
    API.get('client/survey', {
      survey: this.state.employee_company.survey_name
    }, function(res) {
      debugger
    })
  }

  render() {

    debugger

    return (
      <h2 className="text-charcoal text-left">Employee Rubric</h2>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your functions rely on asynchronous requests, which mean they set the state with requests' results after they've returned, if that makes sense.

In you render method, check for the validity of your state and return null if it's not valid. The render method will be called again next time the state is set (i.e. when your requests succeed because the state is set in their callbacks).

Answer (score 0):

How about you pass the authorization token as a prop from a parent component, and then use componentWillReceiveProps hook to fire off the request to the API?